# Transparent status bar covers Action Mode on Kitkat

Tags: android, statusbar, actionmode

I have an activity with the fragment. From this fragment I call method to show Contextual Action Bar and here is my problem.

Styles:

```
<style name="MyThemeLight" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/MyCloseButton</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/ContextualBar.Light</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyMainActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/close_white</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/PopupMenuLight</item>
</style>

<style name="MyMainActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo</item>
    <item name="android:height">1dp</item>  </style>


<style name="ContextualBar.Light" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo</item>
    <item name="android:height">56dp</item>     </style>

<style name="OverFlow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
<item name="android:src">@drawable/menu_white</item>    </style>  

<style name="MyCloseButton" parent="android:style/Widget.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>   </style>    
</resources>
```

Layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layoutright"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layoutleft"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+android:id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<fragment
    class="...BookmarksLeft"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_listleft"
    android:layout_width="306dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:tag="bookleft"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<fragment
    class="...BookmarksRight"
    android:layout_width="306dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:tag="bookright"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

As you can see, main style has no action bar, status bar is transparent, "android:windowActionModeOverlay" is true and "android:fitsSystemWindows" is true but I get:

[image]

Is there any way to move CAB down?

Comment: Have you found an answer for this ? I'm running into the same problem ...

Answer (score 0):

Just change paddingTop and height.
And then add your actionMode style in AppTheme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/CustomActionMode</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionMode" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionMode.Inverse">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">25dp</item> 
    <item name="height">80dp</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/Title</item>    
</style>
```